# how to git commit to different repo

Tags: git

I'm building a set of scripts that should dump and restore specific tables in a database. I want to keep the scripts that do the work separate from the dump of the tables. And I want to commit the dump file of the tables into a different repo as a backup mechanism.

Right now the only solution I can find is to make the backup repo a submodule of the scripts repo, but that means I need to update the scripts repo with the commit hash of the submodule every time I do a commit to the backup repo. This is not ideal.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Git is not a good backup solution. Is there some reason why you are thinking git would be a good tool for this?  Also, if this is just a backup why would the two repos need to be related at all?  Just create a completely separate repo in a separate directory.

Comment: the dump needs to be imported in a different database using a CI-tool so the git repo doubles as backup and transportation and the scripts need to be run by an ordinary user (no devops type of person) so I want to make it as easy as possible for him.